Why can't you define a variable in a print statement?
I'm teaching Python to beginners, and got a question that initially stumped me. One of my students asked me why you can't define a variable in a print statement:
y = [1, 2, 3]
print(x=sum(y))

My assumption is that you can't define a variable in a print statement (or a function call in general) because it would conflict with the syntax for named parameters. I told the student that you can only define a new variable on a new line, or in certain special cases like a for loop (we haven't covered lambdas).
Am I correct in my reasoning for why you can't define a variable in a function call, and are there any circumstances where this isn't true?

That's not a print statement, by the way (that was removed in Python 3.0); it's a print function call. You can only put expressions (including assignment expressions) in a function call expression. You can also only pass keyword arguments the receiver defines; print has no x argument. Something like print("foo", "bar", (third := "baz"), sep=(sep := ", ")) would be fine, calling print and defining sep and third.
